# Search By date in jqgrid Search Toolbar not working

Tags: asp.net, json, search, jqgrid

I am using `Jqgrid` with Asp.net. I am trying to implement Toolbar Search . Every Field is searchable but Date search is not working.. I seen some example and they are working because they are using local data and date formate in source is `2012/02/02`. But I am fetching data directly from data base so Plz Help me to fix this problem.

Here is my Date Col module

```
               name:'Date',
               index:'Date',                                                                                  
               align:"center",
               formatter:'date',                                                                 
               formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'},                               
               searchoptions: 
               {sopt: ['eq','ne'],
               dataInit : function (elem) {
$(elem).datepicker({ changeYear: true, changeMonth: true,  showButtonPanel: true});
                                        }}
```

Comment: In which format exactly you return information for `'Date'` column from the server? Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` or not?

Comment: Data type= datetime ,load once = true

Comment: The parameter `datetype` can be `"json"`, `"xml"`, `"local"` and so on? There are no `load once` or `Data type` options of jqGrid. There are only `loadonce` and `datetype`. All wrong written parameters will be just ignored. How you send today's day for example? Do you sent it as `"2012-11-05"` or in another format?

Comment: data type is "json" and formate is mm/dd/yyy--11/05/2012

Answer (score 0):

You should use additional property `sorttype: "date"` in the definition of the column `'Date'`. Moreover you should verify that the server return date values in correct format.

If you use only `newformat` property of `formatoptions` then jqGrid try to read the data in ISO 8601 format: "Y-m-d". If the server return date in another format you should describe the format with respect of additional `srcformat` property of `formatoptions`. For example `srcformat: "m/d/Y"`.

Comment: I add sorttype: "date" but it is still not working and Date from server returned like this"11/5/2012 12:00:00 AM".